# Passing the "correct" Data from the selected cell in a UITableViewController to a ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I have a `UITableviewController` where I take a JSON file and break it down into various objects for display on my `tableview` (this works fine).

I've also created variables to store certain information from the cells generated in the `tableview` to be passed on to a `detailViewController` (text and images).

Using the 'prepare for segue' method I am able to pass the information I need to the `detailViewController`. However, I keep running into an issue where the data displayed in the `detailViewController` isn't the data of the cell selected but rather the data of what appears to the the last loaded cell on the table.

I am not using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` because it doesn't seem to do much better but create an additional segue screen (automatically).

In summary, my `TableViewController` displays about 4 cells at a time on the screen. regardless of which cell I select, the information passed to the `DetailViewController` is always the information on the fourth cell displayed on the screen.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Post Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

var dict = jsonArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.postTitle.text = dict["data"]!["post_title"] as? String
        cell.postTag.text = dict["data"]!["post_tags"] as? String
        cell.postAddress.text = dict["data"]!["post_address"] as? String

titleToPass = cell.postTitle.text
postTagToPass = cell.postTag.text
addressToPass = cell.postAddress.text



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "ListToDetail") {


            let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailPostViewController

            viewController.passedTitle = titleToPass
            viewController.passedPostTags = postTagToPass
            viewController.passedAddress = addressToPass


            }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that providing an answer will require either ESP or seeing your code.

Comment: update code along with snapshot , it helps to get answer faster

Comment: I've provided snippets - thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called for every cell, so it makes sense that your variables will always have values matching the last cell to be updated.

Instead of setting the data you want to pass in that method, call `indexPathForSelectedRow:` in `prepareForSegue` and use the row of the index path to get the right things from `jsonArr`.

Comment: Thanks i suspected that was an issue but didn't know how to rectify it. I'm still very new at this. I tried the indexPathForselectedRow in prepareForSegue but keep getting errors. Any help with the proper format for the method will be appreciated.

Comment: Figured out the code through trial and error. Everything works fine and thanks again for the suggestion.