# Passing the “correct” Data from the selected cell in a UITableViewController to a ViewController

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm having the very same trouble [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295019/passing-the-correct-data-from-the-selected-cell-in-a-uitableviewcontroller-to) I have not figured out yet how to pass the correct data from TableViewController to another ViewController. I get data from JSON I have everything I need but by selecting any row data showing is the data in the last row. I need to get the information about the exact row I select the TableViewController.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()

func getData(_ link: String) {
    let url: URL = URL(string: link)!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard let _: Data = data , let _: URLResponse = response , error == nil else {
            return
        }
        self.extractJSON(data!)
    })
    task.resume()
}

func extractJSON(_ data: Data) {
    let json: Any?
    do {
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    } catch {
        return
    }
    guard let dataList = json as? NSArray else {
        return
    }
    if let countriesList = json as? NSArray {
        for i in 0 ..< dataList.count {
            if let countriesObj = countriesList[i] as? NSDictionary {
                if let countryName = countriesObj["country"] as? String {
                    if let countryCode = countriesObj["code"] as? String {
                        TableData.append(countryName + " [" + countryCode + "]")
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(String(describing: countryName), forKey: "name")
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(String(describing: countryCode), forKey: "code")
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {self.doTableRefresh()})
}

func doTableRefresh() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    getData("http://www.kaleidosblog.com/tutorial/tutorial.json")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return TableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: You can use tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath to get your data and pass it to vc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath` Delegate Method

```
let string = TableData[indexPath.row]
```

to get your data and pass it to vc

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let string = TableData[indexPath.row]

    let vc = // Your VC From Storyboard 
    vc.data =  string // 
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but I didn't find the way to use it. How do I use this block of code?

Comment: You need not call this method anywhere. tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is delegate method of UITableView. It is called when selection happens.this method informs the delegate that the specified row is now selected.

Comment: @VahidGR You can put it anywhere in your code and you done !!, Accept answer if it helps

Comment: @MikeAlter Oh yeah I forgot to do that :D Thank you

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Once you have passed the context how would you load a specific chat conversation from a specific **message_id**?

Comment: @tymac if you have another question then please ask new question if you can't find similar questions

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Tells the delegate that the specified row is now selected. Use `indexPath` to locate the new selected row in tableView.
Declare a var in your next view controller.

```
var yourObject:String!
```

You can access data of selected cell using indexpath of selected cell and thenceforth send data to next view controller. Access the var of next view controller `yourObject` and pass required data.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let string = TableData[indexPath.row]

if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController ") as? SecondViewController {
    viewController.yourObject = yourObject
    if let navigator = navigationController {
        navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
  }
}
```