# How to pass only one key value pair from array?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The following is my json response....

```
{"Doctor":[{"doctorname":"ANBU SURESH RAO, D.ORTHO., MSORTHO.,","presid":"1008"}]}
```

The following is my viewcontroller code.......

```
let parameters: Parameters=["hnum":hnum!]
    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            let result = response.result
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                if let innerDict = dict["Doctor"]{
                    self.namesarray = innerDict as! [AnyObject]
                    self.jsontable.reloadData()

                }
            }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return namesarray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell
   let name = namesarray[indexPath.row]["doctorname"]

    cell?.lbldocname.text = name as? String
    flag = !flag
    flagcheck()
    return cell!
}
```

This view controller loads only my doctor name, so when i click the doctor name I want the presid only to be passed on to the next view controller.... I tried with prepareForSegue it didnt work....any ideas????

Comment: show your didselect row delegate method code

Comment: you need to get that key value while performing segu or you can pass array to second controller and read values there.

Comment: @DSDharma...i don't have it...since i dont know to use it....can u put it up here?

Comment: @nithinsampath I have added the required code in steps for you to use in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Tells the delegate that the specified row is now selected. Use indexPath to locate the new selected row in tableView.

Check my previous [SO ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166116/passing-the-correct-data-from-the-selected-cell-in-a-uitableviewcontroller-to/45166766#45166766) for details.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let pressId = namesarray[indexPath.row]["presid"]

      if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController ") as? SecondViewController {
           viewController.pressId= pressId
           if let navigator = navigationController {
                navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
      }
   }
}
```

Declare a global variable pressId in SecondViewController so that you can access it from your current controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable selectedPresId. Implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and in that method set the pres id in that global variable

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

selectedPresId = namesarray[indexPath.row]["presid"]
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)

}
```

In prepareForSegue do this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
    let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
    vc.selectedPresId = selectedPresId
}
```

And in your second view controller create a property with the name - selectedPresId so that you can set it in above line vc.selectedPresId